# Create custom convex path Android

Tags: android

I wish to set a custom shape (different radius for each corner of rectangle) to my frame layout, so that views in the frame layout will clip to the shape's bounds.

```
    ViewOutlineProvider provider = new ViewOutlineProvider() {
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                configurePath(getWidth(), getHeight());
                outline.setConvexPath(borderPath);
            }
        }
    };

    setOutlineProvider(provider);
    setClipToOutline(true);
```

And the `configurePath()` looks like this:

```
private void configurePath (int width, int height) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return;
    }

    borderPath.rewind();

    float minSize = Math.min(width, height);
    float maxRadiusWidth = 2 * Math.max(Math.max(topLeftRadius, topRightRadius),
            Math.max(bottomLeftRadius, bottomRightRadius));

    if (minSize < maxRadiusWidth) {
        borderPath.addRect(0, 0, width, height, Path.Direction.CCW);
        return;
    }

    // Top left circle
    oval.set(0, 0, 2 * topLeftRadius, 2 * topLeftRadius);
    borderPath.moveTo(0, topLeftRadius);
    borderPath.arcTo(oval, 180, -90);

    borderPath.rLineTo(width - topLeftRadius - topRightRadius, 0);

    // Top right circle
    oval.set(width - 2 * topRightRadius, 0, width, 2 * topRightRadius);
    borderPath.arcTo(oval, 90, -90);

    borderPath.rLineTo(0, height - topRightRadius - bottomRightRadius);

    // Bottom right circle
    oval.set(width - 2 * bottomRightRadius, height - 2 * bottomRightRadius, width, height);
    borderPath.arcTo(oval, 0, -90);

    borderPath.rLineTo(-width + bottomRightRadius + bottomLeftRadius, 0);

    // Bottom left circle
    oval.set(0, height - 2 * bottomLeftRadius, 2 * bottomLeftRadius, height);
    borderPath.arcTo(oval, -90, -90);

    borderPath.rLineTo(0, -height + bottomLeftRadius + topLeftRadius);
}
```

When I run it, I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be convex` and I could not get into `native_isConvex()` and see how it decides if a path is convex.

So what is a convex path? Why the path in `congfigurePath()` is not convex?
 How can I create a custom convex path? Thank you.

Comment: Facing the same problem. For now, I know that when I use only `lineTo` methods, `isConvex` can return `true`. Using `quadTo` or `arcTo` causes that `isConvex` returns `false`. Maybe this can be some tip…

Comment: @pxsxYeah, `arcTo` is what I thought that causes the issue. But I have to use it because I was planning to create custom shape for view group. Anyway, I solved the custom shape problem with clipPath instead.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by myself. The path is not convex because I was not drawing the path correctly. The correct path that achieve the multiple corner radius effect I wanted should be:

```
    // Top left circle
    oval.set(0, 0, 2 * topLeftRadius, 2 * topLeftRadius);
    borderPath.moveTo(0, topLeftRadius);
    borderPath.arcTo(oval, -180, 90);

    borderPath.rLineTo(width - topLeftRadius - topRightRadius, 0);

    // Top right circle
    oval.set(width - 2 * topRightRadius, 0, width, 2 * topRightRadius);
    borderPath.arcTo(oval, -90, 90);

    borderPath.rLineTo(0, height - topRightRadius - bottomRightRadius);

    // Bottom right circle
    oval.set(width - 2 * bottomRightRadius, height - 2 * bottomRightRadius, width, height);
    borderPath.arcTo(oval, 0, 90);

    borderPath.rLineTo(-width + bottomRightRadius + bottomLeftRadius, 0);

    // Bottom left circle
    oval.set(0, height - 2 * bottomLeftRadius, 2 * bottomLeftRadius, height);
    borderPath.arcTo(oval, 90, 90);

    borderPath.rLineTo(0, -height + bottomLeftRadius + topLeftRadius);
```

Update: Although the path is correct now, it is still not convex path, seems like customized path will not be treated as convex path.

Answer (score 0):

Nice that you got it working, but there are built in tools for this.
Easiest is in a drawable xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />

    <solid android:color="#fff" />

</shape>
```

Programatically you can use the [RoundRectShape](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html) class. That's also what will be inflated from above xml.
In the curstructor you pass outer corner radius, line thickness and inner corner radius. You can also look at the source to see how they create a path (tip: `path.addRoundRect()`).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about `addRoundRect(RectF rect, float[] radii, Direction dir)`. But according to `Outline`'s source code: `public boolean canClip() {
        return mMode != MODE_CONVEX_PATH;
    }` outline does not support clipping custom shape