# How to create a convex path in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to create a convex path in android (in order to feed it into a ViewOutlineProvider for casting shadows when a specific view is getting its elevation to be more than 0)

I only use path.quadTo(...) which only adds control points, so I was thinking this whole thing will be 1 contour and convex. By my app crashes when using the calculated path, as it causes `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be convex`. In addition, the println() is printing "false"

my current function is:

```
fun calculateConvexPath(topLeftRadius: Float, topRightRadius: Float, bottomLeftRadius: Float, bottomRightRadius: Float, top: Float, left: Float, bottom: Float, right: Float) : Path {
            val path: Path = Path()

            // start from top-left
            val firstPoint = Point(top, left + topLeftRadius)
            path.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y)
            path.quadTo(left, top, left + topLeftRadius, top)

            // move to top right
            path.quadTo(left/2 + right/2, top, right - topRightRadius, top)
            path.quadTo(right, top, right, top + topRightRadius)

            // move to bottom right
            path.quadTo(right, top/2 + bottom/2, right, bottom - bottomRightRadius)
            path.quadTo(right, bottom, right - bottomRightRadius, bottom)

            // move to bottom left
            path.quadTo(left/2 + right/2, bottom, left + bottomLeftRadius, bottom)
            path.quadTo(left, bottom, left, bottom - bottomLeftRadius)

            // move back to top-left
            path.quadTo(left, top/2 + bottom/2, firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y)

            println("path is convex? ${path.isConvex}")
//            path.close() // not working with or without this line
            return path
        }
```

I saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506426/create-custom-convex-path-android) but no help - they couldn't create a convex path either.

The code here is kotlin but a Java answer will (off course) be helpfull.

any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't firstPoint be initialized with Point(left+topLeftRadius, top) instead?

Comment: you are right, and it's a bug. No one noticed since both were top=left=0 
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it WAS working, it ran on a phone and shadows were casting. it's just the android studio who didn't show up the shadow

Comment: Then please accept your answer to close the question.